# Docker rails mongodb (Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable (No server is available matching preference: #<Mongo::ServerSelector)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, mongoid

I'm working on a project required dockerizing a rails application, the app is using mongodb (mongoid gem), and sidekiq & redis.

our goal is to create 3 containers, one for redis, the other is for sidekiq, and the third is for the rails application, we do not want to create a container for mongodb, but we will use the rails app container to connect to the mongodb running on our local machine (because on staging and production we're using mongodb atlas so no need for a mongodb container at all).

Every time I try to run the 3 containers, I get this error when trying to access endpoints dealing with mongo

```
Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable (No server is available matching preference: #<Mongo::ServerSelector::Primary:0x41321220 tag_sets=[] max_staleness=nil> using server_selection_timeout=30 and local_threshold=0.015):
```

and here are the files I used to dockerize my application

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.4.2
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /myapp

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY /docker/entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  elagi_app:
    build:
      context: '..'
      dockerfile: 'docker/Dockerfile'
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: 192.168.1.109:9200
      MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING: 192.168.1.109:27017
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./../app:/myapp/app
      - ./../config:/myapp/config
      - ./../lib:/myapp/lib
      - ./../db:/myapp/db
      - ./../spec:/myapp/spec


  sidekiq:
    build:
      context: '..'
      dockerfile: 'docker/Dockerfile'
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: 192.168.1.109:9200
      MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING: 192.168.1.109:27017
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379
    volumes:
      - ./../app:/myapp/app
      - ./../config:/myapp/config
      - ./../lib:/myapp/lib
      - ./../db:/myapp/db
      - ./../spec:/myapp/spec

    depends_on:
      - 'redis'
    command: 'sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml'
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Remove a potentially pre-existing server.pid for Rails.
rm -f /myapp/tmp/pids/server.pid

# Then exec the container's main process (what's set as CMD in the Dockerfile).
exec "$@"
```

mongoid.yml

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: elagi
      hosts:
        - <%= ENV["MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING"] %>
      options:
        user: 'admin'
        password: 'admin123'
        max_pool_size: 20
        wait_queue_timeout: 15
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
```

[image]

how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: `localhost` from a docker container is the docker container itself, not the host running the container. So `MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING: localhost:27017` is wrong since the mongo server is running on your host. You need to change this to the ip of your machine or the ip of the docker0 network for example.

Comment: changed it to the ip of the my machine "192.168.1.109" , but still the same problem

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the exact same error ? Is your mongodb server configured to allow connections from the network and from any ip ?

Comment: yes I'm getting the same error, not sure about the mongodb server configurations, how to make sure about that ?

Comment: By reviewing the mongodb config options maybe ? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net-options

Answer (score 0):

You are juggling a lot of moving pieces.

First, the exception message you referenced indicates you are using an old version of the driver (`mongo` gem). Update to the current version to get improved diagnostics, including for this particular scenario, as well as bugfixes.

Then, start verifying that each piece is functioning by itself. You are running the database on the host; can you connect to it from the host machine? Are you able to connect to other services on the host from the app container (e.g. ssh)?  Are you able to connect from the app container to other services (e.g. elasticsearch)?